# deploy single file on node.js production server without restarting server and down time

Tags: node.js, deployment

We are planning to start our new project in node.js but I want to be clear on the deployment side. Previously we have some applications written in asp.net. We deploy our applications as websites so when some page changes we deploy only that page on the web server and we don't need to restart the website or server. This type of deployment where we can deploy a particular page reduces our risk of letting those changes go on the production which we don't want to release as opposed to the mvc where you have to deploy the dll. 
So my question is that can we do that kind of deployment on our node.js production site where I can deploy only one changed file lets say 'abc.js' and I don't need to restart the server and the connected users to my site shouldn't experience any issue or disconnection as in the case with .net mvc where user's session is ended.
Sorry if this seems too basic but I need to know.
Thanks